# Is there some ready function to parse %specialfolders%?

Tags: c#, special-folders

I would like my command line program to take file parameters in the form:

```
-out:%MyDocuments%\dummy.xps
```

and having %MyDocuments% automatically replaced with:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

I know it's an easy to write function, but I guess it should be already done somewhere, so I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(variable);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)

The input doesn't need to be a single variable, it can be a 'query', like your path, with variables embedded and it will expand all those it finds/recognises. This is shown in the snippet at the link given:

```
String query = "My system drive is %SystemDrive% and my system root is %SystemRoot%";
str = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(query);
Console.WriteLine("ExpandEnvironmentVariables: {0}  {1}", Environment.NewLine, str);
```

Comment: @Default Apologies, should be `Environment.NewLine`, I skipped it in the snippet.

Comment: just for reference: to point my documents we have to write: %HOMEPATH%\documents